# How to change dropdown box border radius in bootstrap website. (I am using CodeIgniter framework)

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, bootstrap-4

I tried using CSS to change dropdown box corners radius. but it did not work.

this is my view. I need to round corners of my dropdown box as search bar or search button.
[image]

My code in view file

```css
.roundedCategory {
        border-top-left-radius: 2rem !important;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 2rem !important;
        border-top-right-radius: 2rem !important;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 2rem !important;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 form-cols">
  <div class="roundedCategory">
   <?php
     $where = array('status' => 1);
     $rows = get_records_where('ci_categories',$where);
     $options = array('' => trans('all_categories')) + array_column($rows,'name','id');
     echo form_dropdown('category',$options,'','class="form-control"');
     ?>
  </div>                    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:-** Add Your Class in  drop down.

echo form_dropdown('category',$options,'','class="form-control `roundedCategory`"');

Comment: please mark green tick as an accepted answer for future readers also.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have round corners you need to change your class from this `<div class="roundedCategory">` to this `echo form_dropdown('category',$options,'','class="form-control roundedCategory"');`.
You need to insert your class in the actually dropdown, in this case your `echo` which is what is displaying it. The reason your code is not working is because you are adding round corners to your `div` and not the dropdown, hope that will solve your problem.

I also left you an example of what im talking about.

```css
.roundedCategory {
        border-top-left-radius: 2rem !important;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 2rem !important;
        border-top-right-radius: 2rem !important;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 2rem !important;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 form-cols">
  <div class="roundedCategory">
    <input type="text"><!--This one doesn't have the class -->
    <button class="roundedCategory">I have round borders</button><!--This one does-->
  </div>                    
</div>
```